# How do I trick the app into thinking the mouse movement is really me?

Tags: python, automation, mouse, pyautogui

I am attempting to get my script to open up a game through steam and then start a world. This all works fine up until the part where I need to navigate the game. I'm assuming that the modules that let you control the mouse just move to points rather than actually moving the mouse which the game doesn't pick up. The game only becomes responsive when I myself move the mouse around IRL.

I've tried using pyautogui, mouse, pynput, and a couple of more but have had no luck. The game doesn't respond until I intervene. I'd love any help ya'll could give me. Thanks.

Here's some of my code, if it helps.

```py
import pyautogui
import time
def openWorld():
        #pyautogui.moveTo(230, 530, 1)
        pyautogui.click(x=230, y=530)
```

Comment: do you ever call the `openWorld` function?

Comment: Yes. I time.sleep(5) to give me time to click on the app and give it "priority" and then have the program execute after.